# Solution to Second Order DE Confusion

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Write down the solution for $x'' + 2x' + 2x = -1$ that originates at $x(0) = d$, $x'(0) = u$. $d$ and $u$ are the vertical position and horizontal position.

Also, I guess $d$ is sort of like the $x$ and $u$ is sort of like the $y$ for this problem? I say that because they say $d$ has to be the vertical position and $u$ has to be the horizontal.

For the number of solutions for the DE, why do we look at the order of the characteristic equation? More so, why is the solution the sum of the homogeneous and non-homogeneous solution (that is our two solutions).

Comment: a constant is a particular case of a function $g(t)=-1$.

Comment: When I do questions like this I tend to use a transformation to make it homogenous by absorbing it i.e $z =x +1/2$  which should give both the particular and complementary solution.

Comment: @Chinny84: That works for quadratic equations, but not for second order ODE. Here the analogous transformation is $z(t)=e^{t}x(t)$. Which results in an oscillator equation for $z$.

Comment: @lutzL I may be missing something but does the transformation I stated not lead to $$z''  +2z' +2z=0$? That was all I was stating really. :)

Comment: @Chinny84: My bad, I was thinking about the next step in simplifying the equation. Yes, if removing the inhomogeneity is as simple as in this case, one should by all means do it. More systematically, it is the method of finding a particular solution by trying out a general function of the same type as the inhomogeneity. (And knowing that any difference of solutions of the full equation is a solution of the homogenous equation.) ((Which I am sure You know, but is part what nomlylni was asking.))

Comment: @lutzl I should of made it clearer in stating "questions like these" as cases of this second order ode. I didn't intend to provide a full answer as I was commuting at the time. So +1 for your answer :).

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind horizontal and vertical is to rewrite the equation as an order one system by setting $y(t)=x'(t)$. Then
$$
y'=x''=-2x'-2x-1=-2y-2x-1
$$
so you get a first order system in the phase space. Why they gave the vertical and horizontal coordinates in an unusual assignment in the task description one would have to inquire in other places.

---

The second question is basic theory of linear differential equations and even the more general theory of linear algebra as it relates to the solution space of linear systems of equations. Please write in more detail what you know about differential equations, especially those of higher order and systems of order one.

---

One more intricate way to write the equation using the roots of the characteristic equation is as
$$
\left(\frac d{dt}+1+i\right)\left(\frac d{dt}+1-i\right)x(t)=-1
$$
which can be rewritten as system
\begin{align}
\left(\frac d{dt}+1+i\right)y(t)&=-1\\
\left(\frac d{dt}+1-i\right)x(t)&=y(t)
\end{align}
This can now be solved first for the first equation that does not depend on $x$, thanks to the characteristic equation. And after that, $y$ is a fixed, known inhomogeneity for the second equation. Linear first order ODE with constant coefficients always have exponentials as basis of their solution.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of 
$$
x''+2x'+2x=0,
$$
is 
$$
x_h(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}\big(c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x\big),
$$
while a particular solution of 
$$
x''+2x'+2x=-1, \tag{1}
$$
is the constant function
$$
x_p(t)=-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Hence the general solution of $(1)$ is
$$
x(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}\big(c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x\big)-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
The constant $c_1$ and $c_2$ are uniquely determined from the initial data:
$$
x(0)=d,\,\,x'(0)=u.
$$